# PHP Execute a string containing static function call

Tags: php, arrays, string, function-call

I want to execute a string containing static function call

```
$string="ClassName::function()";
```

Let
ClassName=ABC & function=abc

so

```
$string="ABC::abc()";
```

the function abc returns a array

now what i want is

```
$array=$string;
```

It should execute $string and store the returned array into $array

Comment: @Uchiha I think OP want eval. But everybody abuses using of it

Comment: it doesn't work when implemented shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: @splash58 Yep you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval`, but use this with extreme caution.

```
$string = 'Class::function();';
$array = eval($string);
```

Comment: it doesn't work
when implemented shows
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Do you have a semicolon after `$string`?

Comment: the semicolon worked dude. Thanks a lot for HELP. what a silly mistake i made.

Comment: If you think one of the answers was the final solution, please accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call a static method directly by setting the class name is a variable  :

```
$classname = 'ABC';
$array = $classname::abc();
```

Comment: it doesn't work when implemented shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

You can use such exotic construction to avoid using eval

```
class ABC {

  static function abc_func() {
    echo 'abc';
  }
}
$string="ABC::abc_func()";

$i = preg_split('/::|\(\)/', $string);

$i[0]::{$i[1]}();  // abc echoed
```